# Why is File Storage's 'store' method always generate same name?

Tags: laravel

I am testing my api, and I don't understand why this `store` method of File Storage always generates the same name. Is it because I use the same file? I am using Postman to test my api.

```
if($request->hasFile('avatar'))
                $item->avatar = $request->avatar->store('avatar', 'public');
```

Generated Path:

```
avatar/70f34de93f937bc933eb86f76b9c11d6.png
```

But when I use different file, different name. I thought it will always generate a unique name?

Comment: Can you add the file name generated ?

Comment: avatar/70f34de93f937bc933eb86f76b9c11d6.png

Answer (score 0):

Normally your code should work as there is no problem it seems. There is an alternate way to generate unique file name and storing.

```
$filename = uniqid().$request->avatar->getClientOriginalExtension();

Storage::disk('public')->put('avatar/'.$filename, $request->avatar);
```

I think this will work for your case.